# Http status 404- The requested resource is not available

Tags: servlets

I have one `jsp` file which is accessing servlet class `DisServlet` which is calling a method from java class `EmpDao`. When I try to run it on `tomcat server` it is giving the above error. It is working fine for AddServlet servlet . Although all the classes and servlets are in proper packages. Can someone help me out on this. Attaching the image for the following error

[Display Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFk9m.png)

[Getting value from database and pressing go and after pressing go getting above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGIFw.png)

doGet() of DisServlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    EmpDao ed = new EmpDao();
    String i = (String) request.getAttribute("id1");
    ed.dis(i);
}
```

**EmpDao class**

```
public class EmpDao {
    private MyConnection mcon;
    public EmpDao(){

        mcon=new MyConnection();
    }
    public int add(Employee emp)
    {

        PreparedStatement pst;
        int rec=0;
        try
        {
            Connection con=mcon.getConn();
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into Employee1    values(?,?,?,?,?)");

            pst.setString(1, emp.getId());
            pst.setString(2, emp.getName());
            pst.setString(3, emp.getDesig());
            pst.setString(4, emp.getDept());
            pst.setInt(5, emp.getSalary());

            rec=pst.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Connection Problem");
        }
        return rec;
    }

    public void dis(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Here reached"+s);
    }
}
```

disJSP file

```
<body>
<form action="DisServlet">
    <pre>

        Enter the employee id to display : <input type ="text" name ="id1">
        <input type="submit" value ="Go">
    </pre>
</form>
```

web.xml file

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>DisServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>DisServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.accenture.training.DisServlet</servlet-class>
```

Servlet Mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DisServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/DisServlet</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Where is your servlet mapping??

Comment: Add your web.xml to your question so that we can have a look

Comment: Added the web.xml code

Comment: What's the context path of your app, and what's the address displayed in the address bar of your browser when you're looking at the JSP?

Comment: this is the url http://localhost:9090/MyEmployeeProject/DisServlet?id=1

Comment: **when you're looking at the JSP**. That's not the URL of a JSP.

Comment: I created the whole file again in another workspace and it worked